# How to mount a Amazon S3 bucket by using FUSE - S3FS

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

This is driving me up the wall. I am still a little new to Linux but i do understand how to do most of day to day stuff I need to do. What I am trying to do is mount a Amazon S3 bucket to a mount point on my server.

I running Ubuntu server 12.04, it is fully up to date. I followed this guided,

http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/04/20/how-to-install-s3fs-on-an-ubuntu-server/

In how to install FUSE & S3FS on my server. But it just says it can not 'establish security credentials'. I have use a psswd_s3fs file within in the etc and have tried a .passwd_s3fs file within the home folder(/home/USERNAME - that is where I put it). These files do have the access key ID and the secret access key (ID:ACESSKEY) <- format used.

If I changed the chmod on either file, form 600 to say 777, it reports back that this is wrong it needs to have no other permissions. So I know its using the files.

So what I am doing wrong?

Also made a new user, the access details I have been using are for the default user login, but it would not take them either. Not sure how to asign that user to a selected bucket or do I have to do it some other way?

Please help?

UPDATE :

What wanted to know is if the detail I got from Amazon are right, so I downloaded TntDrive to test it in windows and there was no problems. Mounted my drive without any issues....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Do not know why I had this problem, as I did make the file within Linux but basic my password file was not in a Linux readable format.

I used do2unix (just Google it and you find out about it). That fixed my problem and then I could see the Amazon S3 sever.

The next issue I add was that samba would not share the drive out, got to use '-o allow_other' option when mounting the drive.

Note that you will / might have to enable 'user_allow_other' in fuse.conf. (/etc/fuse.conf) You can not miss the option it just has a # in front of it, just remove and then save it.

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 4):

try this link http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon
and also remember that :- The credentials files may not have lax permissions as this creates a security hole.
ie.
 ~/.passwd-s3fs may not have others/group permissions and /etc/passwd-s3fs may not have others permissions. Set permissions on these files accordingly:

% chmod 600 ~/.passwd-s3fs
% sudo chmod 640 /etc/passwd-s3fs

it should work, its working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you:

1 ) Use this format if you have only one set of
credentials:

```
accessKeyId:secretAccessKey
```

2 ) If you have more than one set of credentials, this syntax is also recognized:

```
bucketName:accessKeyId:secretAccessKey
```

3 ) Password files can be stored in two locations:

```
/etc/passwd-s3fs     [0640]
$HOME/.passwd-s3fs   [0600]
```